# Ember.js: Nesting a resource in a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to setup a route with the following:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login');
    this.route('mlb.lineups', {path: 'tools/mlb/lineups'}, function() {
        this.resource('site', { path: 'site/:site_id' });
    });
});
```

The problem is, the nested resource 'site' route is not being recognized. If I change `mlb.lineups` to a type resource, that seems to have funky behavior as well. Ideally I have a root level `/tools/mlb/lineups` and then site specific URLs/resources such as `/tools/mlb/lineups/site/1` `/tools/mlb/lineups/site/2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resources/routes can not live under routes.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources